"What if we never met", "life would be boring"
Could you pls tell me,what does it mean?

What if we never met?
Life would be boring.

Whether the sentence is referring to mixed third condition as in

If we had never met, life would be boring now

or 2nd condition referring to future as in

If we did not meet, life would be boring

Or is it referring to present regret as in

If we were not together,life would be boring


You can easily check those online or even on this site.

@Lambie yes I did search them online but to be honest i got confused figuring out the right answer.

The standard would be: If we had never met, life would have been boring. Past conditional. Yours is a mixed conditional and acceptable.

@Lambie thank you for your answer but i was asking about "What if we never met", "Life would be different"

That's not in your question, is it? Edit your question then.

@Lambie I have rephrased my question. Kindly have a look.

People often use things like "if we never met" to mean if we had never met.

@Lambie what i understood is, saying "if we never met, life would be boring= if we had never met, life would be boring. But do you not think the same sentence could also refer to second condition as in future too? "If I did not meet you, life would be boring"

What's the significant difference between "If we never met" and "If I didn't meet you"?

@Barmar yeah, no difference but the second clause is making me confused "life would be boring" "If i never met you, life would be boring" is it for future as in 2nd conditional?

It's not specific about the time frame, it's just talking about their life in general. The implication is that being in a relationship made life more interesting, and those things would not have happened.

[minor point: is confusing me, not making me confused. :)]

Read my answer carefully. People think met is always past but it really isn't in terms of standard conditionals.

@Lambie Yes sure i do.

All conditionals including past conditional refer to *hypotheticals". The difference between first and second is that the second one is stronger than the first. There is even less of a chance of the thing happening.

If we never meet, we will be happy. present/future
If we never met, we wouldn't know each other. simple past/conditional
If we'd never met, we wouldn't have known each other. past  perfect/past conditional
Those are standard. BUT people do this:
What if we never met to mean: what if we had never met, the past conditional.
Then they do this:

What if we never met, life would be boring. Which is standard but not really the meaning they were after. because in many cases they believe they are referring to the past.

But if we never met is not really the past in terms of standard uses of if. It's hypothetical.
Another example:
If you came early, I would meet you.
In that example, can you see that came early is not a past tense but a hypothetical situation?

thanks indeed for making me understand with such a detailed and explained answer. I appreciate.

@BilalZafar [I appreciate it. :)] Thank you.
